# Using std::reverse to reverse the order of the first few elements of a vector

Tags: c++, std, reverse

If I have a

```
vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

How to use

> std::reverse

to turn it into

> vec {2, 1, 3, 4}

Comment: {2, 1, 3, 4} is not the reverse of {1, 2, 3, 4}. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: maybe you want to swap (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/)?

Comment: I just want to reverse first two elements, does the std::reserve only support reverse the whole container?

Comment: You can reverse the first two elements by using `std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 2);` but simpler would be `std::swap(vec[0], vec[1]);`

Comment: reverse reverses the whole array; if you want to swap only two elements, use std::swap, as @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 suggested; std::swap(vec[0],vec[3])

Comment: Thank you so much Neil, but I did not understand iterators quite well, could please tell me why it should be std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 2) instead of std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1), if I want to reverse the first two elements?

Comment: @user2840454, The end iterator is one past the end because it plays nicely (e.g., the pair easily being able to represent an empty range)

Comment: Thank you Chirs. Got it now.

Comment: By convention algorithms often work on a pair of iterators, where the first iterator points to the first element and the second iterator points one past the last element. When you reverse the whole vector, `vec.end()` isn't an iterator to the last element `4`, but an iterator to one more past it. It's not allowed to dereference this iterator as it doesn't point to a real element. When you only want an algorithm to work on a specific range, the second iterator should point to one past the last element you want to be included. In this case, that points to `3`, to get there from begin is 2 steps.

Comment: @user2840454 Please help improving the quality of StackOverflow by marking your accepted answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reverse` with iterators as arguments like this:

```
vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4};
reverse(vec.begin(), vec.begin()+2);
```

[You may take a look here](http://ideone.com/nZta1s)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `std::reverse` for what is essentially a much simpler operation. If you want to just swap the first two elements, use:

```
std::swap (vec[0], vec[1]);
```

If your desire is to swap elements in *groups* of two (leaving any odd one at the end alone), you can use something like:

```
for (int i = 0, lim = vec.size() - vec.size() % 2; i < lim; i += 2)
    std::swap (vec[i], vec[i+1]);
```

If you want to reverse a section of the vector that's *more* than two elements, that's where I'd be contemplating the use of `std::reverse`. You could reverse sections of the vector `vec` containing `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` with calls like:

```
std::reverse (vec.begin(),     vec.end()      ); // -> {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
std::reverse (vec.begin(),     vec.begin() + 3); // -> {3, 2, 1, 4, 5}
std::reverse (vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 4); // -> {1, 4, 3, 2, 5}
```